# I want to know how to make my Tweets private

Tags: twitter, privacy

How can I make my Tweets private so that they can only be viewed by the person I am sending them to?

Comment: Sounds like a job for email, honestly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [Direct Messages](http://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/109-tweets-messages/articles/14606-what-is-a-direct-message-dm).

You need to follow the other person and they need to follow you, then you can send each other DMs and no one else will see them.

Unless you [protect](http://support.twitter.com/groups/31-twitter-basics/topics/107-my-profile-account-settings/articles/14016-about-public-and-protected-accounts) your Tweets all Tweets are public by default.

Even when you protect your Tweets **all** your followers will be able to see any Tweet you post.